# Should [google-talk] and [google-chat] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

From Google's view point, they are one and the same product, Google Talk. So my question is: should the two tags ([google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk) and [google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat)) be merged?

From [google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk)'s excerpt:

> Instant messaging and VoIP app provided by Google that can be accessed through Gmail, iGoogle and orkut as well as the Windows desktop program. Also known as **Google Chat**.

So, yes, I think they should be merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been completed.

All questions with the [google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat) tag have now been converted to the [google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk) tag and a synonym has been created.