# Make [gmail-chat] synonymous of [google-talk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Google Chat used to be usable within Gmail, Orkut and iGoogle but the last two services were shut down, so presently Google Chat can be used only within Gmail.

At this time there are two alternatives for chatting within the GMail web interface: the "old chat" (Google Chat) and Hangouts. Each has their own help centre, a different user interface and some distinctive features, like Hangouts in Chrome doesn't require a plug-in for audio and video conversations, among other features.

The [gmail-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-chat) doesn't have information in its wiki tag page. 
Previously, the [google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat) and [google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk) were merged, as I understand this, because in the context of Web Applications they refer to the same service.

**References**
[Should “google-talk” and “google-chat” tags be merged?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/should-google-talk-and-google-chat-tags-be-merged)
[Chat Help - Google Help](http://support.google.com/chat)
[Hangouts Help - Google Help](http://support.google.com/hangouts)

Comment: Well, I suggested it as a [synonym](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest). If enough people vote for it it'll happen.

Comment: I have approved this synonym. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three tags are referred to above:

[google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk)
[google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat)
[gmail-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-chat)

At present the tag at the top has both the two below it as synonyms, as well as [gchat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gchat).

All 82 Qs tagged [google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk) are Closed – which seems appropriate, given the demise of the service in June 2017.

However there is also one Open Q so tagged:

> How to set up Google Chrome to dial phone numbers on webpages with Google Chat?

However it has been deleted (presumably after a migration to Super User, because the “Page Not Found” page is theirs).