# What to do with Google Chat?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have

- [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) for questions about https://hangouts.google.com
- [google-hangouts-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts-chat) for questions about https://chat.google.com

Google recently announced that "Google Chat" will soon be available to chat with people outside from G Suite organizations ([ref](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/05/talk-to-people-outside-of-your-domain-in-Chat.html)). Inviting a `@gmail.com` user sends and invitation to use https://chat.google.com.

Previously, "Google Chat" was referred as "Google Hangouts Chat". This change is mentioned in a banner on the [Google Chat Help](https://support.google.com/chat).

[image: Hangouts Chat is now Google Chat. You might temporarily see references to both names until this change rolls out everywhere.]

Several years ago "Google Chat" was the web version of Google Talk.

On Web Applications, currently [google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat) points to [google-talk](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk)

Should we keep the tags as they are or should we do some changes?

Comment: Back in 2011 [May you convert Google Chat into its own tag?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/should-google-talk-and-google-chat-tags-be-merged) got the tags to merge. But I think it was always a misunderstanding all because someone mentioned `Google Chat` instead of `Gchat` in `Google Talk`'s excerpt. In any case, as you mentioned nowadays `google-hangouts-chat`'s excerpt is completely wrong (I've submitted a fix, let's hope they accept). It's a shame for months no moderator here has agreed to fix this. All you have to do is rename `Google-Hangouts-Chat` to `Google-Chat`.

Comment: @ LCW Gchat is one of the colloquial names. The official name is Google Chat. See https://web.archive.org/web/20111208075436/http://support.google.com/chat/ among other places including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk

Comment: Wikipedia isn't too clear about that, they might as well meant to write Gchat. Be it as it may, as of 2020 Google Chat is an active service, except not according to this site which claims Google Hangouts Chat uses chat.google.com (while it's the new Google Chat that uses it).

Comment: That go nowhere, anyway, renaming [tag:google-hangougs-chat] to [tag:google-chat] it's something that community members without a diamond can't do, and maybe community memberts with a diamond might not be able to do either because, as it was already mentioned in the question, the later already exists (and it's a synonym of [tag:google-talk]).

Comment: Well, those with enough privileges should delete the synonym first, only then rename.

Comment: While no one here fixes this, "[in 2021, \[Google\] will start migrating **all** remaining customers with “Chat and classic Hangouts" and "classic Hangouts only" settings selected to **Chat**.](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/changes-to-google-chat-migration.html)".

Comment: Maybe it's time to start thinking on a different way to use tags in Web Applications or even to think about on... , well, there a lot of things to think about around this site.

Comment: Why is it related? BTW, G Suite is not even the newest name ("Workplace" is). In any case, "[the future upgrade **from Hangouts to Chat**...Next year, Chat will become available as a free service—both in the integrated experience in Gmail and the Chat standalone app](https://blog.google/products/workspace/latest-google-hangouts-and-upgrade-google-chat)".

Answer (score 1):

I made [google-hangouts-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts-chat) a synomym of [google-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chat)

Comment: It's a bit problematic as many posts there (all but the most recent ones) literally meant the chat of hangouts, i.e.they need to at least get changed to [tag:google-hangouts].

Comment: That is not something new as [tag:google-hangouts-chat] always was intended to be used for questions about the app that is now called [tag:google-chat].

Comment: Then I think it should remain as such while [tag:google-chat] should be standalone.